# ASP NET MVC Session lost at refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, null, refresh

I am currently using Session["Name"]="a name" in my controller which work. But when I try refresh the page the session gets empty. Anyone know why?

My config file got:

sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">

with provider to connectionstring

Answer (score 1):

First try adding the following attribute to your sessionState element (in web.config):

```
timeout="10080"
```

(that's 1 week, in minutes).

Your session *should* then survive for at least several minutes. Since you're storing it In Proccess (mode="InProc"), when your IIS App Pool's worker process recycles all the session data stored in that process will be lost.

If you need to store session data for longer periods of time than your worker process will be alive (or if you want to use multiple worker processes or even multiple web servers), you'll need to store your session out-of-process (e.g. in SQL, on a network share, or in AppFabric).